# Wcf Data Service Service operations

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services

Getting error when I run the wcf data service with the code following the error message:

```
"The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs for more details."
```

Code:

```
public class WcfDataService1 : DataService<Entities1>
    {
        // This method is called only once to initialize service-wide policies.
        public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
        {
            // TODO: set rules to indicate which entity sets and service operations are visible, updatable, etc.
            // Examples:
            config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.All);
            config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("GetData", ServiceOperationRights.All);
            config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2;
        }

        [WebGet()]
        public IQueryable GetData(int Id)
        {

            if (assayId > 0)
            {
                var query = from a in this.CurrentDataSource.Entity
                            where a.ID == Id
                            select a;

                return query;
            }
            else
                throw new DataServiceException(400, "ID is not valid");

        }


    }
```

The same code works when I dont return anything from the operation.

UPDATE: The server logs say:

```
"WebHost failed to process a request.
 Sender Information: System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult/44530215
 Exception: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The service '/MyWcfDataService.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: The type 'MyWcfDataService', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found.. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The type 'MyWcfDataService', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found.
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.CreateService(String normalizedVirtualPath)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.ActivateService(String normalizedVirtualPath)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
 Process Name: WebDev.WebServer40
 Process ID: 1124

For more information, see Help and Support Center at
```

Can anyone please help me with the solution.

Also, if I want to expose my own entity and not the one created by EF, how to go about doing that.. any ideas??

Comment: "See server logs for more details." -> What did the logs tell you?

Answer (score 0):

Just modified the return type to

`IQueryable<Entity>` and it worked.